# one form for both edit and update by mass asignment in laravel

Tags: laravel-4

i have to use one form commonly for both Create and update data in laravel using mass assignment. I used the following code

For Create

```
 public function create() {

        $this->layout->content = View::make('suppliers.create')->with('action', 'storesupplier')->with('method', 'POST');

    }
```

For Update

```
public function update() {

             $this->layout->content = View::make('suppliers.edit')->with('user', Supplier::find($id))->with('action', 'updatesupplier')->with('method', 'POST');;


        }
```

I made a cmmon view as follows

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => $action, 'class' => 'form-horizontal locations'))}}
<p> Supplier Code</p>
    {{Form::text('SupplierCode', '', array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
    {{$errors->first('SupplierCode')}}
<p>Supplier Name </p>
    {{Form::textarea('SupplierName', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'cols' => '2', 'rows' => '1'))}}
    {{$errors->first('SupplierName')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

I think i did most correctly but when use for update, i dont know how  i will replace input::old('supplierCode') .

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Form::model()`, it does all the work of loading data for you:

```
@if($action == 'storesupplier')
    {{Form::open(array('route' => $action, 'class' => 'form-horizontal locations'))}}
@else
    {{Form::model($user, array('route' => $action, 'class' => 'form-horizontal locations'))}}
@endif
<p> Supplier Code</p>
    {{Form::text('SupplierCode', '', array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
    {{$errors->first('SupplierCode')}}
<p>Supplier Name </p>
    {{Form::textarea('SupplierName', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'cols' => '2', 'rows' => '1'))}}
    {{$errors->first('SupplierName')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

Note: this is a quick, dirty and not tested solution, just to show you how easy it could be.